# Determine who is listening on fifo named pipe

Tags: bash, named-pipes, fifo, mkfifo

Say I have a named pipe:

```
mypipe="foobar"
mkfifo $mypipe
```

#### ... later on say I want to write to it

```
echo "foo" > $mypipe
```

if nobody is listening, I am pretty certain this echo call just hangs. Is there a way to determine if anyone is reading from the pipe before I make the echo call?

Comment: You seem to be setting yourself up for a race condition. What is the problem with the call just hanging until someone is ready to read the data?

Comment: I agree re: the race condition, but for my use case, if someone is not ready to read then, they will never be ready, basically, so I will just exit/return before attempting to write

Comment: If the reader dies between the `fuser` call and the `echo` call, you still havo the same problem. Checking with `fuser` so you can avoid timeouts for `echo` most of the time is a valid optimization, but you still have to cope with the possibility that `echo` will hang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fuser` utility tells you who holds an open handle, but in the general case, it requires `root` privileges.

Quoting the [manual page,](https://linux.die.net/man/1/fuser)

> `fuser` may only be able to gather partial information unless run with privileges. As a consequence, files opened by processes belonging to other users may not be listed and executables may be classified as mapped only.
>
> Installing `fuser` SUID `root` will avoid problems associated with partial information, but may be undesirable for security and privacy reasons.